# ASP.NET MVC 2 compile error with partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Yet another compile error for me:

> Error  1   'Model' conflicts with the declaration 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl.Model'   c:\Users\Kevin\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HandiGamer\HandiGamer\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\AdminGameReviewViewModel.ascx   10  51  HandiGamer.WebUI

I'm trying to use a partial view to handle both Create and Edit functionality.  So, my Create view is:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<HandiGamer.WebUI.ViewModels.AdminGameReviewViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Create New Review
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>Create New Review</h2>

    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Create New Review</legend>
            <%: Html.EditorForModel() %>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>

     <% } %>

    <div>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to Menu", "Index") %>
    </div>

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="CSSandJavaScript" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

And the partial view is:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<HandiGamer.WebUI.ViewModels.AdminGameReviewViewModel>" %>

<p>
    <%: Html.Label("Game Title") %>
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.GameData.GameTitle) %>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.GameData.GameTitle) %>
</p>
<p>
    <%: Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.GameData.Genre) %>
    <%: Html.DropDownList("Genre", new SelectList(Model.AllGenres, "GenreID", "Name", Model.GameData.GenreID)) %>
</p>
<p>
    <%: Html.Label("Platforms") %><br />
    <% for (int i = 0; i < Model.AllPlatforms.Count(); ++i) { %>
       <%: Model.AllPlatforms[i].Platform.Name %> <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(plat => plat.AllPlatforms[i].IsSelected)%><br />
    <% } %>
</p>
<p>
    <%: Html.Label("Review Title") %>
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.GameData.Content.Title) %>
</p>
<p>
    <%: Html.Label("Review") %>
    <%: Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.GameData.Content.Text) %>
</p>
<p>
    <%: Html.Label("Review Score") %>
    <%: Html.DropDownList("Score", new SelectList(new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, "ReviewScore")) %>
</p>
<p>
    <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.GameData.Pros) %><br />
    <%: Html.TextBox("Pros[]") %><br />
    <%: Html.TextBox("Pros[]") %><br />
    <%: Html.TextBox("Pros[]") %><br />
    <%: Html.TextBox("Pros[]") %><br />
    <%: Html.TextBox("Pros[]") %>
</p>
```

The line in question is the one that attempts to create the first DropDownList, specifically when I write Model.AllGeneres.  That invocation of Model is what's throwing the error.  It's confusing since none of the other attempts to access Model trigger an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first few html helpers in your partial are using the capital 'Model' instead of lowercase 'model' for the lambda parameter. You have

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.GameData.GameTitle) %>
```

But it should be

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.GameData.GameTitle) %>
```

Comment: Yup, you're right.  What a brain fart that was on my part.  Kept looking at it wrong.  Thanks!